# pyqt5 - Problem switching back from QDialog window to QMainWindow

Tags: pyqt5

Hope indention is OK. I removed the reference to the current instance but the issue is still there. Closing the QDialog window with 'x' the MainWindow is displayed for a second and then it close out, while pressing the 'Cancel' button in the QDialog window it works fine.

Thanks for any suggestion

```
'''
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QWidget, QMainWindow, QDialog
from MainW import Ui_f_main
from ShowDialogUi import Ui_f_Dialog

class MainWindow(QWidget, Ui_f_main):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()       
        self.setupUi(self)    
        self.wDiag = None   
        self.pbDialog.clicked.connect(self.dialog)

    def dialog(self):
        if self.wDiag is None:
          window.close() 
          self.wDiag=ShowDialog()         
          self.wDiag.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose) 
          self.wDiag.destroyed.connect(self.resetFlag_wDiag)
          self.wDiag.show()    
          self.wDiag.pbOK.clicked.connect(self.go_on)
          self.wDiag.pbCancel.clicked.connect(self.go_back)
        else:
          self.wDiag.close()
          self.wDiag=None

    def go_on(self):
        print("OK")

    def go_back(self):
        window.show()
        self.wDiag.close()
        self.wDiag=None

    def resetFlag_wDiag(self):
        window.show()
        self.wDiag=None
  
class ShowDialog(QDialog,Ui_f_Dialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self) 

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
'''
```

Comment: 1. please fix your indentation, is completely off and inconsistent; 2. doing `self.window = window` is completely pointless, since it already refers to the current instance; and adding a global reference like that is just wrong.

Comment: sorry for the bad indentation. Is there a way to manage that Main Window will be displayed once the Dialog window is closed by pressing 'x' ?

Comment: Please fix the indentation, remove the wrong references and *test* the code before submitting the post editing, then we'll be able to properly check your code.